# How can I get user media permissions(camera and microphone) of Firefox browser through JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, getusermedia

The code below is working properly in the chrome browser:

For microphone:

```
 navigator.permissions.query({name: 'microphone'})
    .then((permission) => {
        console.log("microphone state", permission.state);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Got error :', error);
    })
```

For camera:

```
 navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'})
    .then((permission) => {
        console.log("camera state", permission.state);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Got error :', error);
    })
```

The same code above is not working in the Firefox browser where I am getting the following errors:

**For microphone:**
Got error:

> TypeError: "'name' member of PermissionDescriptor 'microphone' is not
>   a valid value for enumeration PermissionName."

[image]

**For camera**:
Got error:

> TypeError: "'name' member of PermissionDescriptor 'camera' is not a
>   valid value for enumeration PermissionName."

Anyone having an idea how to get the user media permission state for camera and microphone in the Firefox browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I did something similar recently, and it worked on Firefox:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { audio: true, video: false } )
   .then( ( stream ) => {
        // microphone available
   },
   e => {
        // microphone not available
   } );
```

Taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API).

Comment: It also works for me but my requirement to get user media permissions like allowed, denied and prompt(ask default). Are you able to get navigator.permissions.query in firefox??

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/19) issue on GitHub (specifically [this](https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/19#issuecomment-370158947) comment), Firefox simply doesn't support camera and microphone.

There are some [reasons](https://github.com/w3c/permissions/issues/180#issuecomment-405443847) for this, which are probably too technical, so this feature you are trying to implement is not achievably at the moment (until Firefox figures it out)

Best regards <3

Comment: No problem! If you find a solution/workaround for this by yourself, feel free to add an aswer to your own question, otherwise, consider accepting an answer to your question if it suits you :)